# Php require use keyword

Tags: php, include

I have a php file with many use declarations.

Use.php

```
<?php
    use 'class/MyClass1';
    use 'class/MyClass2';
?>
```

File1.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'Use.php'
?>
```

I would like to include it on another php file but it doesn't seem to work.

Must I need to copy/paste all Use declaration on every php file ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

> Note:
>   Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

So you can't move `use` statements into a separate file, unfortunately.

If you've got multiple files that have a large set of similar dependencies, it *could* be a sign that your code needs reorganising, but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !